# Is there a way of seeing the evolution of the statistics of a site as a function of time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, statistics, data-analysis

Is there a way of seeing the evolution of the statistics of a site as a function of time?

For example, I would like to see these statistics (e.g. number of visits, regular users, number of questions, number of answers per question, etc., i.e. any statistic that is reasonably relevant to analyze the growth or quality of the site as a function of time) of AI SE (or any other SE, really) as a function of time, e.g., how they have evolved in the last week, month, year, etc. Maybe as graph would be nice.

Maybe the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/) could be used, but I've never used it, so I don't really know how it works.

I am aware of the fact that moderators can access certain site analytics, but I think it would also be useful if other users could access some of these statistics and see their evolution, but, at this point, you could argue that the argument is now whether regular users should have access to them or not.

Comment: There's also the analytics page, which you can access with a diamond or enough rep: https://ai.stackexchange.com/site-analytics (has data on traffic, votes, and posts, though not # users or % answered)

Comment: Tapping the [tag:statistics] turns up Q&A's listing dozens of SEDEs such as: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342560/282094 or this similar request to enhance the mod tools https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103247/282094

Comment: There's 10k site analytics and IIRC they're better than our mod ones :D