# What if Monica runs for Moderator in an open election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

There is [an agreement between Monica Cellio and SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/217279) about the slander issues.

And an offer to consider [using the moderator reinstatement process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336176/217279) which everyone knew before the offer was made she would never agree too.

With normal elections being a more open process, what happens if Monica runs for election?  Does Stack Exchange prohibit her from running, or do they let her stand for election with everyone else?

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate, no time to check right now): [Can a fired moderator be elected as a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334728/295232)

Comment: (Monica's case has been discussed explicitly in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336903/369403) of the proposed duplicate, which is by no means official but I wouldn't expect one anywhere).

Comment: I find it extremely unlikely that they will deny her the diamond after letting her run and possibly win, as that will undoubtedly raise controversy on even more sides. Either they'll initially deny her the nomination, or they'll let her run and regard the election result.

Comment: @AskAboutMonica Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/273494  Right now, moderators everywhere have the ability to exclude people they don’t like from being able to stand for the elections on any site where they may be held to replace those of us that resigned. The ban is for any suspension any where on the network as far as I know, so the appointed moderators here on Meta suspending people keep Meta from being too negative has a serious side-effect they may not have considered.

Comment: I suggest that SE issue a general amnesty to all who they felt offended by, including Monica of course, and to anyone who chooses to apply for reinstatement to their status (and their rep) prior to The Mess.  Not that I think it will happen, but, with the proper language, legal and otherwise,  it is a no-fault way out of the impasse.

Comment: @AskAboutMonica All of those suspensions (on non-deleted accounts) were handed out by local MSE mods for violating rules here, not by SE employees. Also, the moderator guidance has explicitly stated for years to disregard the 1-year election ban when levying suspensions.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog - In your first comment, did you mean to say "disregard"? // Could you explain your second comment, please?  I didn't understand what you're getting at.  Maybe a link would help?

Comment: @ab2MonicaNotForgotten - I would upvote such a proposal.

Answer (score 7):

Well, per the agreement

> We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute. We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community. In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

The key takeaway there is that Monica isn't actively blacklisted from being a moderator (they wouldn't invite her to reapply if she were). She has also not been suspended on any site I am aware of (which would [disqualify her](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114)). As such, Monica seems to be free to run for moderator on any site she is qualified to run on.

Comment: Let's all vote for Monica, on whichever site she decides to run. I will.

Comment: "they wouldn't invite her to reapply if she were" This is a non trivial assumption.

Comment: I sincerely doubt Monica is going to run for election on any site at this point.  After the way SE treated her, it's unlikely she trusts them in the same context in the future.  I mean, would you?